# how can pass and get the list with 2 different item to the razor view on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model, razor-pages

Hi I want create form for create and update in asp.net core.
I have 10 file input that user can choose their image like this:

```
 <div class="form-group mt-1">
     <label>image 1 :</label>
     <input asp-for="Multimedia" type="file" class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 border-bottom border-bottom-2 border-dark" id="Multimedia" name="Multimedia" accept=".jpg">
 </div>
```

and my model like this:

```
    public List<Tuple<IFormFile? ,string? >> Multimedia { get; set; } = new List<Tuple<IFormFile?,string?>>();
```

I create list for model, so I can use foreach for search and send data to database. But my action function not Triger after click on submit button. also I want use this model properties, so in update form if user not enter the file I can still track the index and if user not input the new file means I do not need the update for that. like this:

```
<div class="form-group mt-1">
                                    <img src="~/assets/product image/@Model?.Multimedia[i].item2" class=" img-thumbnail rounded rounded-5    my-1 "
                                         style="width:75px;height:75px;" />

                                    <input asp-for="Multimedia" type="file" class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 border-bottom border-bottom-2 border-dark my-1" id="Multimedia" name="Multimedia" accept=".jpg">
                                </div>
```

also when I use 2 different list for iformfile and string like this:

```
  public List<IFormFile?> Multimedia { get; set; } = new List<IFormFile?>();
public List<string?> MultimediaAdress { get; set; } = new List<string?>();
```

I can set and get data in razor view, but for example in update form if we have 5 preview image and 5 input file and user not set the third file we have list with 5 item for MultimediaAdress and 4 item for Multimedia so we can not correctly compare it for update.

the final way is I define 10 string and 10 IFormFile variable. but in this way i should check each of them separately. this way is easiest and worked but I do not think it is the best way. also in another project if we do not know how many file we have this is not work either.
how can fix my problem. and what is the best way for solve it?
sorry if i can not explain very well because of lack of my English language experience.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement about the images.

Let's say you want to create a banner for yourself, then the banner should contain several images for the yourself.
Or what you want is many images and each of the images is used for different target.

Then we could design the model like this, have a list for banner which is a list of iformfile, and image1/image2 for different targets:

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public string StaffName { get; set; }
        public List<IFormFile> bannerImgList { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Image1 { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Image2 { get; set; }

    }
```

Then in the controller(I test in an MVC project)

```
[HttpPost]
        public string Submit1(TestModel model) {
            return "hello";
        }
```

And in the view:

```
@model WebAppMvc2.Models.TestModel

<form asp-controller="Test" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="Submit1" method="post">
    <div>
        <div>this is for defining IformFile properties</div>
        <div class="form-group mt-1">
            <label>image 1 :</label>
            <input asp-for="Image1" accept=".png">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-1">
            <label>image 2 :</label>
            <input asp-for="Image2" accept=".png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>this is for multiple files</div>
        <div class="form-group mt-1">
            <label>image lists :</label>
            <input asp-for="bannerImgList" multiple accept=".png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="click me" /></div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. but this is worked only for create form. but not in update form because the null value not send to server with form. for example by default I have 10 file input and 10 image for one item. currently in this way. I create 3 list for preview (string), flag (bool) and file(IFormFile) in my model. also create one img tag for show user the current image. create 2 input text with none display for preview name and flag(with false value) and finally the file input. (and repeat this for all image exist. so if user do want update some image we turn their flag to true.

Comment: then in server side we add null to file list, in place flag index is false. in this way we can track the index correctly an compare if some image need update or not. i find this solution almost 3 hour age. are this solution is currect?

Comment: thank you for your reply but it's hard for me to understand your requirement, maybe you could share a picture for your website? and according to your description, it looks like a complex update and create progress, is it possible to re-design the product?'